# Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' to 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The situation: when I press a button in rentViewController, it pops up a tableviewcontroller. If a specific cell has been pressed, it sends data to rentViewController. In order to send data from one view controller to another I needed the code

`let rentViewController : RentViewController = self.presentingViewController as! RentViewController` <- here is where the error shows up

so that tableviewcontroller could get access to the variables and functions from rentviewcontroller. I'm using

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to get out of the tableviewcontroller and back to the rentviewcontroller. However, it gives me an error "Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' to 'RentViewController'". I did some research and I think it's according to the orders of my view controllers but I'm not sure how to change it in a way that it works. My initial view is 'TabBarController' and the order after that is 'NavigationController' -> 'RentViewController' -> 'TableViewController'. If you have questions feel free to ask I can provide you more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your viewController is being presented from UITabBarController. With approach you are using I believe you can access it like this (where index is index in UITabBarController of your UINavigationController containing RentVC):

```
if let tab = self.presentingViewController as? UITabBarController, 
    let nav = tab.viewControllers?[index] as? UINavigationController,     
    let rentViewController = nav.viewControllers.first as? RentViewController {

        rentViewController.data = data
}
```

However, I would suggest using a delegate or callback block to pass data in this occassion.

For delegate approach, first create protocol:

```
protocol PassDataDelegate:class {
    func passData(data:YourType)
}
```

Then in TableViewController:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: PassDataDelegate?
}
```

And in RentViewController:

```
extension RentViewController: PassDataDelegate {
    func passData(data:YourType) {
        //use data to suit your needs
    }
}
```

Before presenting TableViewController, in RentViewController, set its delegate:

```
tableViewController.delegate
present(tableViewController, animated: true)
```

And finally, inside TableViewController, before dismissing, call delegate's method to pass data:

```
delegate?.passData(data: <<someData>>)
```

Comment: Tried the first method and it worked! Thank you so much. What's the reason why you suggest using delegate to pass data?

Comment: It is cleaner way then to depend on call order. For example, if later on you decide to present TableViewController from different point in the app, delegate would still work, while depending on hierarchy might not.