# Passing Data between view Controllers Using a segue from a view embedded in a navigation controller to a tabbarcontroller

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have two views that I would like to pass data from one view to the next. The first view is where I have the data that I would like to pass to the next view lets call it `SourceViewController`. However `SourceViewController` is embedded in a `NavigationViewController` and the secondViewController lets call it `DestinationViewController` is the firstView in a `TabViewController`.

I have tried to use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480327/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitabbarcontroller-to-viewcontroller) and it fails to go past navigation view it just skips the whole logic.

This is my code :

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "loginSuccessSugue") {

        if let tab = self.presentingViewController as? UITabBarController,
            let nav = tab.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController,
            let destinationVC = nav.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController {


             destinationVC.currentBalance = serviceBalance
        }

    }
}
```

This is the `HomeViewController`:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UICircularProgressRingDelegate{

var currentBalance = 0.0

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    circularBalance.maxValue = CGFloat(currentBalance)
     print(currentBalance)

   }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(currentBalance)
    circularBalance.setProgress(value: CGFloat(currentBalance), animationDuration: 3)

     }
}
```

This is how the storyboard looks like:

[image]

Comment: are you presenting your 2nd VC ?

Comment: sorry I just rechecked I am using a present modality segue if thats what you are asking

Comment: and you are not using any TabBar in your app right ?

Comment: yes I am using a Tabbar

Comment: so HomeViewController is your destination VC ?

Comment: Yes HomeViewController is the destination

Comment: put a breakpoint at this `destinationVC.currentBalance = serviceBalance` line and see if this line gets executed or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my view controller where you can check that I am sending 5 to tabbar first viewcontroller:

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: self)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let destinationNv = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
        let destinationViewController = destinationNv.viewControllers[0] as! FirstViewController
        destinationViewController.currentBalance = 5
    }
}
```

Now You can check my firstview controller where you can check that what value we are getting.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentBalance = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print(currentBalance)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Now, You can check my console and storyboard: 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) docs:

> var presentingViewController: UIViewController?
>
> The view controller that presented this view controller.

Which would work great for you, ** **IF** ** you were trying to go back in your navigational hierarchy, as did the guy in the [SO post you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480327/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitabbarcontroller-to-viewcontroller).

You are trying cast the **VC THAT PRESENTED SOURCEVIEWCONTROLLER** of your `SourceViewController` as a `UITabBarController`, which fails miserably, and is why you never hit a breakpoint inside your nested `if let`'s.

If we look the next variable down from this in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621407-presentedviewcontroller) we can see something that will take us forward to the `UIViewController` we are presenting:

> var presentedViewController: UIViewController?
>
> The view controller that is presented by this view controller, or one
>   of its ancestors in the view controller hierarchy.

So now to go over the code you need to solve your predicament. I'll give you the same code you posted, but fixing the tense of my verbs in the comments:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "loginSuccessSugue") {

                               //ing -> ed
        if let tab = self.presentingViewController as? UITabBarController,
            let nav = tab.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController,
            let destinationVC = nav.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController {


             destinationVC.currentBalance = serviceBalance
        }

    }
```

Isn't it frustrating when the English language tricks you up more than swift?

EDIT:

Since you are passing the data in `prepareForSegue:` you will actually want to get the `UITabBarController` from `segue.destination`. And since the the `UITabBarController`'s `ViewControllers` property will be nil or empty in prepare for segue. This is a bad approach for passing the data.

You may need to create custom subclass of `UITabBarController`, pass it the variable, and then pass that data to its `viewControllers` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    var serviceBalance : Double?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Make sure vc is not null or empty before continuing.
        guard let vcs = viewControllers, !vcs.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        if let navVC = vcs[0] as? UINavigationController, let destinationVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as? UIViewController {
            destinationVC.serviceBalance = destinationVC
        }
    }
}
```

Updated `prepareForSegue:`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let tabBarVC = segue.destination as? MyTabBarController {
        tabBarVC.serviceBalance = serviceBalance
    }
}
```

**Don't forget to change the `UITabBarController`'s class in the identity inspector of storyboard to `MyTabBarController`**

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `if()` condition code.

Use below code will get your `HomeViewController` in destination of segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "loginSuccessSugue") {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? HomeViewController {
                destinationVC.currentBalance = serviceBalance
            }
        }
    }
```

As in `segue.destination` you will get your `HomeViewController` so no need to get it from **Tab + Navigation** stack.

Edit:

```
let destinationVC = segue.destination as? HomeViewController
Print(destinationVC)
```

Hope this solution will helps!

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. Here is how I am consuming the currentBalance from the HomeViewController.     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print(currentBalance)
        circularBalance.setProgress(value: CGFloat(currentBalance), animationDuration: 3)
    }

Comment: so you mean to say you are not getting currentBalance in your home vc ? or you are unable to set it into progress bar ?

Comment: yah I'm unable to get the balance in HomeViewController. Even if I print it in viewdidload

Comment: ohh ok, can you show me your var currentBalance in home screen ?

Comment: I have updated the code for HomeViewController on the question

Comment: what you get while you print this value in home vc?

Comment: I get 0.0 when I print in viewdidload

Comment: As per my exp now problem is in your `serviceBalance` variable is it working as expected ?

Comment: I even added  destinationVC.currentBalance = 100 and still it didn't work

Comment: try one thing put break point in `destinationVC.currentBalance = serviceBalance` its going there or not ?

Comment: it just goes to if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? HomeViewController then it skips everything

Comment: have you replaced my code with yours ? do one thing print as per my updated code in my answer is it getting desination VC or not ?

Comment: I just checked its not getting destination view controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168295/discussion-between-dvixextract-and-codechanger).

Comment: `segue.destination` will be the `tabBarController` check his storyboard screenshot.