# Segue to a view controller embedded with a tab and navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

[The Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0UxC.png)

Hello so basically i'm trying to segue from 1 to 2 and show that screen when the button is clicked. What is happening is that the tab controller is not shown but the navigation is when it segued back to view controller 2. I'm not sure if this should be done programmatically or through the storyboard but I tried searching for a solution online and I haven't seen anybody explain this broadly.

Comment: **Please try this** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665361/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-a-segue-from-a-view-embedded-in-a-na/49804588#49804588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `tabBarController` selected item index programmatically like this when the button is tapped,

`self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1` // 0 or 1 as you have two tab items

And you have to remove the segue for that `ViewController` 2 as it is the first `ViewController` in that tab so once you set the `selectedIndex` of `tabBarController` you will get that `ViewController`

Comment: What if view controller 2 has a another view controller connected to it and I want to go there?

Comment: @Jov yes you can trigger that segue in `ViewController` 2's `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I also tried this but this goes to the same page which is 2 and just removes the tab controller

Comment: did you remove the segue also?

Comment: yes I did. I tied up the button iboutlet and then there I put the selectedIndex and change the value to 0 and 1 and when you click the button it slides as if it's moving to another page but it's just the same page and removes the tab bar controller underneath it.

Comment: Slide can not happen if you changed the tabBar selectedIndex. Please check the segue's.

Comment: Yes it's still not showing. In the view controller 2 though there is not even a tab bar after embedding it to a navigation controller. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I have an example for an application having TabBar, it might help you. You can check it here https://github.com/kamirana4/SwiftComponents/tree/master/TabBarExample

Comment: Hello yes I saw your project it's different than mine though and what i'm trying to achieve which is simply moving to a new view that is inside another navigation bar both embedded in a tab controller. Perhaps you can try to build the project like in my image and see how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I have already given answer of that type of question

**Please have a look:**

[Passing Data between view Controllers Using a segue from a view embedded in a navigation controller to a tabbarcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665361/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-a-segue-from-a-view-embedded-in-a-na/49804588#49804588)

Comment: Hi i'm asking more about how to bring that page up with the tab controller. I understand the preparing the data to send part but actually switching to that view with the tab controller is what i

Comment: Have you tryied simple push?

Comment: Yes i'm using push.